# How to add an even to object in Angular and FabricJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, fabricjs

I am new in angular 5 and FabricJS. I made class in which i got object `vrchol` and metod `changeColor`. I want to add event to `vrchol`, but that isn't working.

`this.vrchol.on("mouseover",this.changeColor);`

`changeColor(){ this.vrchol.set("fill","green");}`

Answer (score 0):

On `mouseover` event, set cache dirty to true and render the object, so it will reflect the changes.

***DEMO***

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 100
});
canvas.add(circle);
circle.on('mouseover', onMouseOver);
circle.on('mouseout', onMouseOut);

function onMouseOver() {
  if (this.fill != 'red') {
    this.set({
      'fill': 'red',
      'dirty': true
    });
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
}

function onMouseOut() {
  if (this.fill == 'red') {
    this.set({
      'fill': 'black',
      'dirty': true
    });
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  }
}
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.6.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='c' width=400 height=400></canvas>
```